# Как записать данные в массив из .txt, если формат записи числа через запятую 0,0?

Tags: python, numpy, csv

У меня есть массив в .txt файле записанный через пробел:

```
0,144   0,937   1,787   -1,052  -0,192
```

Хочу записать данные в массив NumPy. Нашел функцию `numpy.loadtxt()`.

Но так как формат записи не через точку (0.144) а через запятую (0,144) - получаю ошибку.

Comment: ну можно просто предварительно заменить запятую на точку ``string.replace(",", ".")``

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь [pd.read_csv(..., decimal=",")](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html):

```
import pandas as pd

arr = pd.read_csv(r"/path/to/file.txt", sep="\s+", decimal=",").to_numpy()
# NOTE: -----------------------------------------> ^^^^^^^^^^^ ^^^^^^^^^^^
```